# Remove right margin / padding from ionic layout

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello I just did a fresh install of ionic, actually just learning it however when I loaded it my browser I saw something I didn't like.

[image]

[image]

There appears to be a right margin I cannot get rid of, I have tried and tried but nothing seems to work.  How do I remove it?

This is my html:

```
<ion-header>   <ion-navbar primary>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Welcome, Person</ion-title>   </ion-navbar> </ion-header>

<ion-content class="no-padding no-margin">

    <ion-grid class="data-table no-padding no-margin">
      <ion-row class="header no-padding no-margin">
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
          <span class="label">
              <span class="text col">Customer</span>
              <span class="col">
                <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
            </span>
          </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">Invoice #</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">Type</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">Amount</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">Method</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">No. of Tickets</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col justify-content-center padding>
            <span class="label">
                <span class="text col">Date &amp; Time</span>
                <span class="col">
                  <img src="assets/imgs/up-down-arrows.png" class="icon" />
              </span>
            </span>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

  <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.   </p>

  <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button> </ion-content>
```

This was a fresh ionic installation so it was like that before I even added my custom css.

Comment: It was actually a fresh ionic installation, so it was like that before I added any html or css and even after taking out my  css it's still there.

Comment: Ionic Version 3.20.0

Comment: Tried that, didn't work, this is very weird.

Comment: Just confirmed that it's only like that when I use my pc browser, not like that on mobile.

Comment: Alright after research I finally understand that that space is meant for the scrollbar, or am I wrong?

Comment: Probably, it looks like :) isn't it needed on mobile too?

Comment: Probably because mobile uses touch scroll that might be why it doesn't appear but it's weird though because normal scroll behaviour is to have enough content before the scroll bars are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue which `<ion-card></ion-card>` has left and right margins, it didn't help when I set `no-margin`, then I checked [Overriding Ionic Varialbles](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) and now the issue solved,  you can check the site yourself and do your modification.

```
// App iOS Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// iOS only Sass variables can go here
$card-ios-margin-left: 0;
$card-ios-margin-right: 0;



// App Material Design Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// Material Design only Sass variables can go here
$card-md-margin-left: 0;
$card-md-margin-right: 0;



// App Windows Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// Windows only Sass variables can go here
$card-wp-margin-left: 0;
$card-wp-margin-right: 0;
```

See attachedf image, left side is the original `ion-card` and right side is the one with settings(black part are the phone frame).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could not implement custom padding if you want to inherit it from parent so:

```
<ion-content no-padding>
```

If you have to do with ion-card try this css:

```
width: 100% !important;
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
```